# add ssh keys in Docker

Tags: git, docker, ssh

in my Dockefile i am adding ssh key to the docker and cloning a project from bitbucket.
i can pull another branch in the Docker file easily.

```
ARG key
ARG pub_key
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
RUN ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
ADD $key /root/.ssh/
ADD $pub_key /root/.ssh/
RUN git clone git@bitbucket.org:******************/sql.git
WORKDIR "/sql"
RUN git pull origin testBranch
```

the repo is cloned sucesfully and and a pull is made successfully from the `testBranch` 
when i run this docker using `docker run`  command and try any git command it says

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

but the ssh key is present in the directory `/root/.ssh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key is added against **root** user (`/root/.ssh/`). I guess when you run `docker run` you are switching to another user (maybe, **docker**).

If you add your `id_rsa.pub` to correct user (the user after running `docker run` command) then it should work.

`$ whoami` show you the current user.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing keys as args you can also mount host's .ssh directory into docker with following options:

```
docker run -v /home/<host user>/.ssh:/home/<docker user>/.ssh <image>
```